# htaccess to rewrite subdirectory with image

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a new, hobby, website I have a problem when a subdirectory is called directly.

When you goto http://www.placewomen.com/222/222/image.jpg the image is loaded directly. But when you goto http://www.placewomen.com/222/222/ I've got a premission error because there is no index.html/php to show image (which I also don't want there...!).

What I would like to happen is when subdirectory is called the page is shown with the image.jpg. The subfolders are generated dynamicaly.

I'm a frontend developer myself and the knowledge to make this happen through the htaccess is "a bit" to much for me....

Any help is highly appreciated!
greetings
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/image.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/image.jpg [L]
```